# OBIEE 11g OBIApps RPD Update row count, NQ_SESSION.USER_LANGUAGE_CODE "No value defination"

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, business-intelligence, obiee

The repository in OBIEE 11g is a prebuilt RPD from oracle OBIApps. The connection pool is appropriate and is working.

But while updating the row count there are few variables which pop up and as they are default so i press them "OK".

But then there is an error message which is stated as

```
nQSError23006:The session variable, NQ_SESSION.USER_LANGUAGE_CODE, has no value
```

Then I tried to disable the session variable by disabling initialization block.

Then also the same error is popping up.

**Please guide me with this error.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Variable was being pointed from the Standard Views by oracle where in the the view was written with a where clause.

Where Clause was as follows:

```
select * from xyz where language_code = 'NQ_SESSION.USER_LANGUAGE_CODE'.
```

Answer (score 2):

That means the variable is (re-)used as a reference in - for example - other initialization block SQLs, calculations or generally inside other repository objects and is still being queried. Or at least "attempted to be queried".

Best search across your RPD for references to that variable.